# C# Recursive Folder/File scan with Size,Path,Creation,FileVersion to txt

Tags: c#, recursion

I am looking for a recursive function that scan a specific folder and send result in a text file.

I would like to list in a text file all files and folder with size, path, creation date, file version if existing but I have no idea on how to proceed.

I found some way to scan recursively but not to recover all needed information.

Comment: What have you tried?  This is one of the simplest recursive methods you can write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following,

```
    GetFileInfo(string dir)
{
 try
       {
           FileInfo info = null;
           foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sDir))
           {
               foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(d))
               {
                info =  new FileInfo(file);
                //get all information using info here
               }
               GetFileInfo(d);
           }
       }
       catch (System.Exception excpt)
       {
           Console.WriteLine(excpt.Message);
       }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the System.IO.FileInfo object and System.IO.DirectoryInfo object....other than that, show us what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can list a folder using System.IO.DirectoryInfo and System.IO.FileInfo as ganders said.If you can list one folder's content the rest is simple recursion.The idea is while listing root directory if one item in the root directory is a directory call the same function on this directory.